# FIX issue with new order single

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, forex

I am new to  FIX technology and am working on a FIX application. Whenever I send a `NewOrderSingle` message, I get an error.

I am using the QuickFix engine in C# and creating `RequestPlaceOrder` objects and filling the required fields. The FIX message in the `RequestPlaceOrder` is as

```
8=FIX.4.49=11235=D 1=GtlXXXXXX 11=USD/CHF_2 21=1 38=30 40=2 44=20 54=1 55=USD/CHF 59=0  
60=20120123-03:45:42 207=GTLXXXX 10=069
```

In the above message, I have not included the header and trailer message since it’s mostly common and appended by QuickFix engine.

Response:

```
1/19/2012 12:57:00 AM :
8=FIX.4.4?9=108?35=3?34=6?49=GtlXXXXXXX ?52=20120118-19:27:00.828?
56=PFSORDER?45=6?58=Required tag missing?371=14?372=8?373=1?10=151
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send tag 14 (cumqty) as it is required by your counterparty. I am guessing that your counterparty uses it for something so check your rules of engagement; tag 14 is not normally in NOS messages so you may need to add it as a custom tag.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure what tag 14 would even mean on a `NewOrderSingle`, but that does seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your messages for completion on [Fiximate](http://fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/).

And pay attention to the tag **371** which mentions which tag is missing or is being referred to.